# Error en deploy con NameError: name 'static' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

Al subir los archivos al server en pythonanywere me genera la siguiente linea de error. Alguna idea de ¿como solucionarlo?

```
 File "/home/factura/wp/wp/wp/urls.py", line 36, in <module>
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
NameError: name 'static' is not defined
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from django.conf import settings

    urlpatterns = [

        path('admin/', admin.site.urls)...
    ]

   if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
**urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)**
```

**Estructura de directorios**

```
├── Projecto
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   │   └── projecto
│   │       ├── css
│   │       ├── img
│   │       ├── js
│   │       └── vendor
│   │           ├── bootstrap
│   │           │   ├── css
│   │           │   └── js
│   │           ├── font-awesome
│   │           │   ├── css
│   │           │   ├── fonts
│   │           │   ├── less
│   │           │   └── scss
│   │           └── jquery
│   └── templates
│       └── root
├── media
│   └── projects
├── facturacion
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── templates
│       └── factura
└── wp
    └── __pycache__
```

**settings.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: Que versión de Django estás utilizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del settings.py de la app debes de poner al final del todo el código

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/nombreUser/nombreProyecto/static'
```

para hacer referencia a tus archivos estáticos, además dentro la configuración que te ofrece *PythonAnyWhere* tendrás que configurar la sección de **static files** como se muestra a continuación:

[image: Static files]

Te recomiendo verificar la ruta de tu carpeta **static**, y verificar que la haz escrito bien.